# Ireland, car hire & SCDW

Tags: car-rentals, ireland

I'm planning a touring trip of Ireland, arriving at Knock airport, so need a hire car.  I've read all the warnings about the hard sell of SCDW that I'll probably get when picking the car up, and I'll definitely need something like that as I don't have a credit card for them to put the £1,500 odd block on.  I've also seen that you can get third party insurance that offers much better features for less.

Would the car hire company/desk ever take the third party insurance as SCDW replacement, so that they don't ask me for a credit card with at least £1,500 on it?

I've looked at various car hire sites and they don't seem to acknowledge the existence of third party insurance.

I'll be limited to car hire companies at Knock airport, so Budget, Avis, Hertz, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. The third party excess insurance will repay *you* if you are billed for damage to the car, not the car hire agency. If the car hire agency requires an authorisation for some amount, they likely won't be persuaded by your excess insurance policy because they can't be sure that the policy will pay out in all circumstances where they would charge you. For example, if you drive drunk and crash the car, this might invalidate the excess insurance policy.

Comment: Or the third-party insurance might pay out but the customer may (willingly or not) use it to pay other debts.

Comment: So my choices appear to be either have a credit card with the available balance or pay their extra charge.  That is annoying.